# jax-ws web service does not work in websphere 8.5

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, websphere-8

Been trying to get jax-ws web service working in websphere 8.5 but no success.
I have tried Java bean & war packaging, stateless ejb & jar packaging but it just does not work.

I am trying to get it work with @webservice annotation.

I am not generating any extra artifacts. I am letting websphere figure out during the deployment. During deployment there is no error. After deployment, I try to run wsdl in the browser to see if web service is installed successfully but I get nothing.

Not sure if I am doing something wrong during the deployment or something else.
Let me know if you want more info.

Regards,

Comment: Check this link http://java-vignettes.blogspot.ru/2011/10/websphere-jax-ws.html

Comment: Konstantin, still no success buddy.

Comment: @RaviTrivedi, "I get nothing" means HTTP 404 or an Exception or just a browser connectivity error?

Comment: @kolossus, yes, correct. it has 404 file not found error. Because websphere does not generate any artifacts during deployment. I confirmed it by checking the directory where program gets deployed and it does not have required artifacts(wsdl, etc etc). So obviously Service Provider(in the websphere GUI where jax-ws gets listed) is also empty. This has become highly intriguing :)

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Had similar problem, but with WAS 7. Have you checked Websphere's log? It pointed me where the error was (very obscure btw, but I managed to figure it out).

Comment: @MiljenMikic, I did check logs, looked alright to me. What did you have in your logs ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Something like 'wsdl couldn't be generated'. The solution was packing wsdl together with war file and pointing Web service to use locally stored wsdl (annotation `@Webservice(wsdlLocation="META-INF/file.wsdl"`). It's quite interesting that the error wasn't logged in SystemErr log file, but in SystemOut.

Comment: @MiljenMikic, let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually websphere 8.5 is Java EE 6 compliant which means that the container should scan the classpath of the web application to find @webservice annotated classes and deploy them as running web services.

However depending on the servlet specification you are using (given in the web.xml file) the scanning will not take place : it should automatically take place starting from version 2.5 of the specification.

For older web applications the Websphere solution is to put a special attribute in the MANIFEST.MF of the related war : the key is UseWSFEP61ScanPolicy and the value true.
see [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_devwbsjaxws.html) for more details.

The servlet 3.0 specification also has a parameter controlling the scanning (it is usually used to speed up the cold start initialization of the application). Putting metadata-complete="true" in the root tag of your web.xml 3.0 deployment descriptor will prevent the scanning to happen (and false enables it)

Answer (score 1):

I was more or less running into the same issue you have, but on WAS 8.0.

Make sure that your web.xml is written for the Servlet 3.0 specification. I was using a web.xml for Servlet 2.4 and updating the version to 3.0 fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Shouldn't 2.5 work ? I think 2.5 and above should work. Because 2.4 and below don't support annotation injection. But I will try with 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem with WAS8.5 It was due to annotation scanning done by both WAS and application. After disabling WAS annotation scanning with "DisableIBMJAXWSEngine" application is able to start.

```
DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you java runtime and project facet are ***1.6*** if you are using WAS 8.0.